# $\log_26-\log_215+\log_220$ Please do not use a calculator

Tags: calculus

$\log_26-\log_215+\log_220$

Should I read this right to left explicitly?

Reading right to left:

$\log_2(\frac{6}{15\cdot20})$

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: Remember that "subtraction" is just adding the negative.  Think of this instead as $\log_2(6)+(-1\cdot \log_2(15))+\log_2(20)$

Comment: The down vote is because someone considers it to be a really "simple" problem. I think so too. So what. You showed your work and you typeset the problem correctly. You deserve an honest answer, which I see you got.

Comment: Which of the following would you say is correct? $$6-15+20=6-35=-29$$ or $$6-15+20=-9+20=11? $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This lis
$$\log_2\frac{6\cdot 20}{15}=\log_2 8=3.$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Notice, $$\log_a(p)-\log_a(q)+\log_a(r)=\log_a(p)+\log_a(q^{-1})+\log_a(r)$$  $$=\log_a(pq^{-1}r)=\log_{a}\left(\frac{pr}{q}\right)$$

As per you question, substitute $a=2, \ p=6,\ q=15, \ r=20$ & simplify you will get the answer

Comment: Quite a strong HINT.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate the expression in any fashion due to commutative laws of addition, but your evaluation is wrong nonetheless. If we iterate from right to left, we have

$$\log_2\Big(\frac{20}{15}\Big) = \log_2\Big(\frac{4}{3}\Big)$$

In conjunction with $\log_2(6)$, we have

$$\log_2(6) + \log_2\Big(\frac{4}{3}\Big) = \log_2\Big(\frac{24}{3}\Big) = \log_2(8) = \log_2(2^3) = 3\cdot \log_2(2) = 3$$